# How to undo an accidental drag and drop

Tags: windows-7, drag-and-drop, undo

This happens to me in Windows Explorer: I mean to open a folder and manage to move the mouse and accidentally drag the whole folder ... somewhere.  Usually I notice, but not always (in which case I know I'm out of luck).  If I notice that it has been dropped into another folder, but don't know exactly where, is there anyway to undo what I just did?

I don't always even notice the folder being grabbed, which makes it more interesting to find where it was dropped.  I just noticed that something happened, and I'd like to undo it, because I suspect that one folder was dropped into another.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Short Answer

To undo a file/folder operation in Windows, you can use either the `Undo` command in the `Edit` menu, or press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>.

## Caveat

**NB**: There are a few things to note however. While the undo command usually undoes the last file operation, it will not *always* be the operation you are expecting. Sometimes the last operation does not make it into the undo buffer, making it undo a different operation from what you were expecting. For example, if there are multiple file operations happening at the same time, they are added to the undo buffer *in they order that they complete, not the order in which they were initiated*. Also, some operations cannot be undone like permanent deletions, those from the command-line, etc.

## Recommendation

Instead of using <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, it is safer to use the menu command because you can see what operation Windows will undo before performing it. (Granted, you can redo the operation with <kbd>Ctrl+Y</kbd>, but it is easier and safer to just confirm before undoing.) Enable the status bar (`View->Status bar`), then when you hover the cursor over the `Undo` command, it will display the operation to be undone.

[image: Screenshot of Windows Explorer with undo command results shown in status bar]

Comment: A wild *.gif appears! How are my screenshots supposed to compete with this now? :P

Comment: I find a (properly timed) animated GIF works better than numerous individual pics.

Comment: @Synetech SuperUSer will never be the same from now on, what gif software do you use?

Comment: +1 for gif and better explantion, even though its a bit late to the party.

Comment: @Moab, the other answers gave the base information. They were lacking the warning and preventative steps, and all three were the same, so it was pointless to edit just one (or all three) to add the extra. (And it was asked just one hour ago. Has computer/Internet time gotten so fast that one hour is “late”?) `o.O`

Comment: Control-Z made me happy. Turning on the menu and setting the View Status bar and seeing exactly what I am doing, that is even nicer.  That was worth waiting an hour for.  Now I'll have to ask the same question about Outlook, although when I last accidentally dropped a folder there, I didn't notice for some time, until I tried to put something in a folder that I KNEW was there.  (I must be too sloppy.)

Comment: Sorry I can’t help with Outlook, I only use Outlook Express. (I have occasionally had similar experiences of accidentally dragging messages in OE around, and found that the easiest way to find them was to use the Find Message command useful; though it does help when moving folders around.)

Comment: "Has computer/Internet time gotten so fast that one hour is “late”?" Yep

Answer (score 7):

**Edit > Undo Move** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. You may have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> first, if the menu bar is not visible.

[image: undo]

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will undo the drag and drop operation. Choosing **Undo** from the **Edit** menu works as well.

Answer (score 3):

To undo the last action, choose **Undo** from the **Edit menu** or hit<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Middle-click or right-click before dropping it to cancel the action entirely. Middle-click is probably more preferable since it won't summon a context menu. This way you can avoid all the caveats of undoing an accidental drag 'n drop.

Comment: I usually press Escape. It's the simplest manipulation for me, and hey, this key is meant for it :)

Answer (score 0):

To add on existing answers:

I sometimes do accidental moves, like so: I'm pretty sure I just made a wrong move, but I don't know what I moved.

When it happens, I usually hover on "Edit > Undo Move" and look at the status bar to know the moved file/folder. I read something like `Undo Move of 'foobar.txt'`. Nice.

But when it happens with several items, I'm getting the text `Undo Move of ''`. Super useful…

This experience on Windows 7. If I recall correctly, Windows XP was showing something like "file 1.txt, file 2.txt…"

So, as a tedious workaround, here is what I (have to) do:

- Run NirSoft [FolderChangesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html) (great software, as usual)
- Start monitoring of the drives I was working on.
- In Explorer, undo the move. Cross fingers.
- Look at the report in FolderChangesView.
- Now with a bit of luck, I know what was the move.
- Take action accordingly: keep the undoing of the move, or redo the move.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:

## 1. Quick Access Toolbar

In Windows 10 this is now accessible from the ***"Quick Access Toolbar"***:

[image: Quick access toolbar]

You just select ***"Undo"*** from that menu, then you can click the back-arrow button as many times as you need to undo file move operations etc.

## 2. Context Menu

You can also right-click on any blank space within Windows Explorer and select the ***Undo move*** operation from the ***Context Menu***:

[image: Windows Explorer undo op via context menu]